# Genymotion: Unable to create virtual device

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

Any clue on why Genymotion can't creaTe a virtual device?    Genymotion returns a list of devices, when I try & select and download one I get the "Unable to create virtual device..." error.   The error in the log is "Could not find a registered machine named ...".  Running as admin did not help.

Any ideas?  proxy server maybe?  I can get the list fine of devices fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have the newest Virtualbox version installed on your PC or the VB-version which comes with genymotion.
If you are using Windows 7 try to run Genymotion in Compatibility mode for Windows XP or try to run Genymotion as admin.

Answer (score 1):

manually install the latest VirtualBox or reinstall GenyMotion will works normally.

to find out why,open your cmd,and type GenyMotion to launch the GenyMotion and check the logs.